# check if model changed since controller loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there an angular way of checking if a model has changed since it's initial state when the controller was loaded ?

I can of course create a variable to store the initial state and compare against it, but is there a more elegant way ?

```
function myController (Service) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.model = Service.getValue(); // Service sets inital value at controller load

        vm.method = function(){
             // do something here only if vm.model changed form inital State
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$watch` on the scope

```
$scope.$watch('vm.model', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    If (newVal) doSomething();
}, true);
```

The optional Boolean for the second parameter allows you to do a deep watch of the variable properties.

Make sure that you inject $scope into your controller too

Answer (score 0):

you should use *$watch* to tracking all change of variable.
View more detail on here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope